# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'poster') at app.js:69:53 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at app.js:68:57

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I keep getting this error on forEach loop:

[image: I keep getting this error on forEach loop]

- JS Code:

*for the first error:*

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItem')).forEach((e, i) => { 
   e.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = songs[i].poster; 
   e.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0].innerHTML = songs[i].songName; 
});
```

*for the second error:*

```
    const music = new Audio('../Audio/1.mp3');
    music.play();
```

Comment: What is `songs`?

Comment: first error is pretty clear to me, either your array `songs` is not defined by the time you run your loop or there is not `poster` key present in your `songs` array

Answer (score 1):

For the first error you should give more info and for second error the problem is that you cant play an audio automatically by yourself and the user should do something(for example clicking the button) and the the music should play. this exception is just in chrome(i think) and its due to security(and these things) You can make all the elements in body `display:none` and make a button `display:block` then when button was clicked play the music and somehow start the program.

EDIT : For the first error the songs[i] can be not an object or it doesnt have a property poster please give this informations :

- Where did you deployed `songs`
- Where did you deployed `songs[i]`
- is it an object or something else?

Comment: Sorry, i just checked my code and came to know that i did'nd add an onClick function to the button.